# The opposite of a rhetorical statement

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase that describes a statement that implicitly requires the audience (a person or persons) to respond with a question? For example, if someone says to you, "I just saw the best movie ever!" You, in turn, are implicitly required to ask, "What movie did you see?" The idea I am looking for would be the antonym of a "rhetorical statement", if such a thing existed.

Comment: A *provoking* statement?

Comment: non-rhetorical ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is simply the nature of conversation. Asking a question is only one of the acceptable ways to move forward in such a scenario. The audience may respond with a guess instead of a question. The audience may pause and wait for a follow-on statement which provides more information. The audience may also choose to ignore the statement entirely and change the subject.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, no such phrase is commonly used in English. The sole exception would be perhaps a **leading** statement or question. That is not to say that it comes before something but rather it prompts the user to subconsciously respond (though not necessarily with a question).

Many attorneys (or at least the good ones) are proficient in this as they can trick the respondent into revealing more information than intended.

There could be such a phrase used by academicians in the field of linguistics however.

Comment: This may be incorrect. A leading question suggests a *desired* answer; it doesn't prompt one to answer.

Comment: Removing the part about the _leading_ question, this I think is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slang term for Facebook status updates that are like this:

> #### Vaguebooking
>
> An intentionally vague Facebook status update, that prompts friends to ask what's going on, or is possibly a cry for help.
>
> <sub>[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Vaguebooking)</sub>

See also: [Vaguebook](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Vaguebook).

---

In real life, I would call it a vague, [attention-seeking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_seeking) statement. (But not to their face.)

Answer (score 0):

You could call this a *prompt*.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/prompt?q=Prompt) gives:

> prompt    verb [ T ]
>
> UK  /prɒmpt/ US
>
> to do something that causes a reaction or makes someone do or think
> something:
>
> *The accusations of fraud prompted an angry response from the company's CEO.*

Comment: Hey! Please don't post any more answers that are only a single sentence like this. You **need** to provide some details as to why your answers are the correct ones.