# What's the name for a non-question posing as a question?

Tags: rhetorical-devices

A rhetorical question is a question that doesn't require an answer.

What's the name for a rhetorical device that's a non-question that requires an answer ?

Eg, in the following convo what role does "Say we did" play ?

> Person A: "We could 'forget' to invite Steve."
>   Person B: "Say we did."
>   Person A: "If he came anyway, we'd know he wasn't a vampire."

My best guess is "implied question". In this case, it would expand to "Let's say we did, what would happen ?"

Can you think of any other examples ?

Note: there's "[The opposite of a rhetorical statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347363/the-opposite-of-a-rhetorical-statement)" which is also looking for the "opposite" of a rhetorical question, but that is about requiring the listener to respond with a question.

Comment: "Say we did" has several words elided.

Comment: @HotLicks i've never heard "elided" used to refer to entire words, but yes, there is a lot that's implied. I'm not a linguist by any stretch, so feel free to fix my question if I've used the wrong terms

Comment: A **leading statement**? "We expected you at the party."

Comment: The term for a yes-no question masquerading as a statement is _declarative question_ (indicated in speech by a rising tone and in print by the usual question mark [So you're a grandparent now?]), but this is different. It's akin to "Go on ...", a conversational organising pragmatic marker requesting further thoughts.

Comment: I'm stuck at the forget part.

Comment: @WeatherVane i considered "leading statement" before posting. but at least for "say we did" i don't know that it's really leading, ie there doesn't appear to be an intent to influence. yosef - good catch, fixed.

Comment: It's leading the other person to continue decribing the scenario.

Comment: @Barmar - I find it interesting that the *leading statement* has a unique inflection (between informative and interrogative).

Comment: You can make leading statements and also ask leading questions.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence *Say we did* is also a declarative statement.

*Forgot* sounds like the elided word: To omit or slur over (a syllable, for example) in pronunciation.

Comment: The question is about the response by person B, not the statement by person A.